# Send message to Admin ( conversation between two clients whit socket.io)

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

How to send messages to a specific client with socket.io?

I need send data between User-Admin.

Here my code.

**Server**

```
socket.on('client', (data) => {
  console.log(data);

  socket.join(data.user);
  io.sockets.to(data.user).emit('server', datos);
});
```

**Client**

```
send.addEventListener('click', function() { 
socket.emit('client', {
    user: user.value,
    msg: msg.value
});
});



socket.on('server', function(data) {
// console.log(datos);
out.innerHTML +=
    `<p>
    <strong>${data.user}:</strong> ${dara.msg}
</p>`;
out.scrollIntoView(false);
});
```

**Admin**

```
socket.on('server', function(data) {
//console.log(datos);
out.innerHTML +=
    `
            <p class="mb-0">
                ${data.msg}
            </p>
    `;
});
```

Help me :(

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
 // sending to individual socketid (private message)
 io.to(`${socketId}`).emit('hey', 'I just met you');
```

Refer to this [cheat sheet](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/)